Embedding $\mathbb R[x,y]$ in the ring of functions $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N\to \mathbb R$.
I was attending a guest lecture at a university... We were discussing various problems. I was amused by the solution of this:

Let $R$ be the ring of all functions from $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ (with usual point-wise addition and multiplication as you'd expect from a ring of functions). Show that there is a subring of $R$ which is isomorphic to the polynomial ring $\mathbb R[x,y]$.

I couldn't solve it. This is the solution given by the lecturer.
We have an embedding $\varphi:\mathbb R\to R$ defined by $c\in\mathbb R$, $\varphi(c)\colon\,\mathbb N \times \mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ which identically maps every $(i,j)$-pair to $c$.
Now, extend $\varphi$ to $\mathbb R[x,y]$ via these assignments for $x$ and $y$.
$$\begin{array}{rl}\mathbb R[x,y]&\overset{\varphi}\to&R\\ x &\mapsto &f_x\colon&\mathbb N\times \mathbb N&\to&\mathbb R\\ &&&(i,j)&\mapsto & i\\ \\ y&\mapsto &f_y\colon&\mathbb N\times \mathbb N&\to&\mathbb R\\ &&&(i,j)&\mapsto & j \end{array}$$
The above determines a ring homomorphism. It's easy to check that it is injective.

In reality, checking injectivity wasn't so easy but I could do it. It required proving this lemma:

If $f\in\mathbb R[x,y]$ is a non-zero polynomial then there is a $(m,n)\in\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ such that $f(m,n)\neq 0$.

It was done using some facts about Vandermonde determinant (the details of which I will share if I'm asked as I don't want to make this question too long and just focus on what's relevant to me.)

As you can see that $f_x:\mathbb N \times \mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ is a map which projects each tuple onto its first component. Similary, $f_y$ projects a tuple onto its second component. I believe, there could be a nice generalization of this problem i.e., embed $\mathbb R[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$ in the ring of functions $\mathbb N^n\to\mathbb R$. The solution seems obvious: assign each $x_i$ to $f_{x_i}$ ($i$-th component projection).
My question is:  What could be the motivation behind assigning projection maps? I am sure someone didn't come with this idea out of thin air. There must be some literature behind this... I believe this is intricately related to property of projections as we see them in linear algebra.

For your injectivity lemma: treat $f$ as a nonzero polynomial in $(\mathbb R[x])[y]$. It can only have a finite number of zeroes. Therefore there's a natural $y$ such that $f(y)$ is a nonzero polynomial in $\mathbb R[x]$, and there's natural $x$ such that $f(y)(x)$ is nonzero.

@sdcvvc Indeed! This is very simple explanation and it can be generalized to more variables and it works not only on $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ but also on $A_1\times A_2$ where $A_i$'s are infinite subsets of $\mathbb R$.  I complicated everything!

To be honest i find this map to be very intuitive: Let for a polynomial $$p\in \mathbb R[x,y], f_p: \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb R, (a,b) \mapsto p(a,b)$$ the induced function.
Now the map he describes is simply sending $p$ to $f_p$. He is sending a polynomial to the polynomial function induced by it.
You can define algebra homomorphism (from a graded algebra, note that $\mathbb R[x,y]$ is such a graded $\mathbb R$-algebra) by defining the mapping on the generators. This is what he does, probably because from his point of view this feels easier and this "obviously" induces an algebra homomorphism, so he doesn't need to do the calculation by hand.
Fun fact: Over finite fields this map (exchange $\mathbb N $ to the field) can't be injective anymore.

Thanks. I didn't realise this: $f_p$ is just a restriction of $p$ to $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$.
